# How do I return objects from a class without using the __str__ method?

Tags: python

I am working on a program that takes in a CSV file of people and returns a population of the people. The file contains a table with the first name, last name, and 5 different traits (Work, Socialize, Hobbies, Eat, Sleep) of the people. Currently, I have a Person class that accepts the first and last name as strings and the traits as dictionaries. I am also defining if the person has an unbalanced or balanced life based on their distribution of the traits. The **str** method of this class is being used to return whether the person is unbalanced or balanced, but I also need to create a list called the population of the person objects, but it is returning the unbalanced or balance status of each person.

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, traits):
    self.first_name = str(first_name)
    self.last_name = str(last_name)
    self.traits = traits
def determine_lifestyle(self):
    check = 0
    check2 = 0
    if(self.traits["Sleep"] != 0 and self.traits["Eat"] != 0):
        for val in self.traits.values():
            if(val == 3):
                check += 1
            if(val == 2):
                check2 += 1
    if(check >= 3 or check2 >= 3):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def __str__(self):
    if(self.determine_lifestyle()):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " has a balanced lifestyle"
    else:
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " has an unbalanced lifestyle"
import csv
def read_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    population = []
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        population.append((row[0],row[1],{"Work":row[2],"Hobbies":row[3],"Socialize":row[4],"Eat":row[5],
                                          "Sleep":row[6]}))
    return population
```

Is there any way to return the person object without using the **str** method?

Comment: `__str__` doesn't return the person object, it is used to provide a *string representation* for when an object is printed.

Comment: Your code never creates any `Person` instances, so it's not clear where your issue is. Perhaps you're doing that in some other part of the code? It seems like you either want a `__repr__` method that gives more information than `__str__` does, or you want to replace `__str__` with something more detailed and move your balanced-lifestyle code into another method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems incomplete, as your `population` variable is holding tuples, instead of `Person` object instances.

If you have a list of `Person` instances, and then you print those instances, their *unbalanced or balanced status* would show up, as `print` would print the string representation of the instance, and the representation is overwritten as you define a `__str__()` method for the class.

> Is there any way to return the person object without using the str method?

If you instantiate a `Person` object, like `aperson = Person(fname, lname, traits)`, then you could get attributes of it though `aperson.first_name, aperson.last_name`, and get its balance status using `aperson.determine_style